# manage game stages in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a class that have a methods that create all my sprites,bodies,enemies,backgrounds of a stage in my game . the init call all this methods and create them on start.

now, i want to add many more stages,and do so in the right way .

i was thinking of creating a new class called : game-handler, so i have 2 classes the one i mention earlier will add the sprites and bodies, and when i need to go the the next level, i will call the game handler with the current stage, and get back strings of the new stage's images,and coordinates .

like that each stage class1 call the handler,get the right values to load,and add the sprites and bodies according to that values.
is that correct ?
the memory management will be ok like that ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is by making my custom CCScene subclass take some configuration values on init. Then I create another class that acts as a manager that will instantiate this CCScene for each new stage and pass it to CCDirector's `replaceScene` method. That way, each stage is a fresh instantiation of the CCScene class so there will be no risk of unreleased memory or reused variable values.

A suggestion on how the manager class looks like:

```
@protocol GameManager : NSObject {
    int currentLevel;
    NSMutableArray *stageConfigs;
}

- (id)init;

+ (GameManager *)sharedManager;

- (void)goToLevel:(int)levelNum;

- (void)goToNextLevel;

@end

@implementation GameManager

...

- (void)goToLevel:(int)levelNum {
   StageConfig *config = (StageConfig *)[stageConfigs objectAtIndex:levelNum];

   GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithConfig:config];
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
   [scene release];
}

...

@end
```